# Hidden divs per each link to show on hover

Tags: jquery, html, image, hover, hidden

I have different links, one per project, and right after it there is a hidden div that has to appear when the relative link gets hovered.
You can see it not working here http://mircofragomena.com/WIP but it can give you an idea.
Every link at the bottom (the projects) have a div hidden, and each of it contains the image of the project. Now just the first project shows the correct image, but not any of the other ones.

This is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".list-item").mousemove(function(e) {
        var offset = $(".list-item").offset();
        $("#hoverDisplay").animate({
            left: e.pageX - offset.left,
            top: e.pageY - offset.top
        }, 1);
    });
});

function toggleHiddenDisplay(id) {
    elem = document.getElementById('hoverDisplay')
    if (elem.style.display == 'block') {
        elem.style.display = 'none';
    } else elem.style.display = 'block';
}
```

The first part follows the mouse position so that the div image gets stuck on the pointer, while the second should make the div appear/disappear on hover..

This is the HTML:

```
<a href="project/index.html" class="project-title" onmouseenter=toggleHiddenDisplay("hoverDisplay") onmouseout=toggleHiddenDisplay("hoverDisplay")>Text.</a>
<div class="hidden-img" id="hoverDisplay" style="display:none;">
<img src='path/1.gif'>
</div>
```

This is the CSS, though I don't think is very useful:

```
#hoverDisplay {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}

.list-item>div.hidden-img {
    display: none;
    height: 500px;
    width: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

As every project has its own hidden-img div right after the a tag, I'd like the div to appear just when the previous a gets hovered.

Answer (score 0):

I've did some changes..
The ID in HTML became a class, so we got .hoverDisplay now

I have tried to identify the target that generated the onmouseenter event by using this code now

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$(".list-item").mousemove(function(e) {

var offset = $(".list-item").offset();

$(".hoverDisplay").animate({

left: e.pageX - offset.left,

top: e.pageY - offset.top

}, 1);

});

});

function toggleHiddenDisplay(id) {

var target = $(ev.target);

var elId = target.attr('id');

if (target.is(".project-title")) {

elem = document.getElementByClass('hoverDisplay')

if (elem.style.display == 'block') {

elem.style.display = 'none';

} else elem.style.display = 'block';

}

}
```

And I've added an ID for each link called #project+N (number 1-12) so that I can detect on which N I do the hover, and trigger it back on the hidden div.

It still won't work and I know that surely something is missing but I'm not a master of JS.

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting to accomplish can be done with CSS using the sibling (+) operator. No jquery or javascript required.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

Example below:

```css
.hidden-img {
  display: none;
}

a:hover+div {
  display: block !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="project-title">proj 1</a>
<div class="hidden-img">
  <img src='https://fakeimg.pl/250x100/?text=project1'>
</div>

<a href="#" class="project-title">proj 2</a>
<div class="hidden-img">
  <img src='https://fakeimg.pl/250x100/?text=project2'>
</div>

<a href="#" class="project-title">proj 3</a>
<div class="hidden-img">
  <img src='https://fakeimg.pl/250x100/?text=project3'>
</div>
```